# Is there any way to import a Mii into the Wii Channel on the Wii U

Tags: nintendo-wii, wii-u

On my Wii, I have a button in my Mii Channel to transfer a Mii to and from my Wii remote, as seen in [this tutorial](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2911/wii_save_mii_character_remote_wiimote/).  On the Wii Channel of my Wii U, I don't have that button.

I've also tried to connect my 3DS using the shortcut (A + B + 1 + 2), which works, but you can't transfer *from* the handheld to the console, only the other way around.

I do not want to do a whole Wii data transfer.  Am I stuck making Miis from scratch on the Wii Channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No.

Besides the data transfer method, there is currently no way to import your old miis to the WiiU, as the WiiU version of the Mii Channel does not support the interaction with the Wiimote storage.